# Draw all the lines object in list, adding,deleting new line after that?

Tags: c#, image-processing

I save some line object in a list and try to draw them once over a picture box, but every time it draw only one line at the middle of the picture box , is there any solution for this problem.
Thanks in advance ...

```
    public class Lines
    {
        public System.Drawing.Point startPoint = new System.Drawing.Point();
        public System.Drawing.Point endPoint = new System.Drawing.Point();
    }

    Lines b = new Lines();
    List<Lines> alllines = new List<Lines>();

//------------inside button click i wrote the following code----------

    b.startPoint.X = rectlist[i].X;
    b.startPoint.Y = (rectlist[i].Y + rectlist[i].Bottom) / 2;
    b.endPoint.X = rectlist[i].Right;
    b.endPoint.Y = (rectlist[i].Top + rectlist[i].Bottom) / 2;
    alllines.Add(b);

    this.OrignalimgPIcBX.Invalidate();
```

and inside the paint event of the picture box i wrote this code

```
Graphics g = e.Graphics;
using (var pen = new Pen(Color.Black, 2))
{
    foreach (var lines in alllines)
    {
        g.DrawLine(pen, lines);
    }
}
```

what is the problem ??!

---

the list of line in now correct 
but know the line objects does not drawn in the correct position

i make the picture box size mode as stretch image , is that make any change!

this is the paint event

```
private void OrignalimgPIcBX_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        Graphics g = e.Graphics;
        using (var pen = new Pen(Color.Black, 2))
        {
            foreach (var lines in alllines)
            {
                g.DrawLine(pen, lines.startPoint, lines.endPoint);

            }
        }
   }
```

Comment: Does `alllines` contain something else than `b` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The is only 3 possible explanations,

- All your lines are the same
- All but one line is drawing out of the view-able area
- Or you are eating up an exception

You need to use your debugger and break point the lines to make sure they are drawing with the correct metrics

**Update**

```
for (int i = 0; i < rectlist.Count; i++) 
{
    var b = new Lines();  // <-- you need to do this
    b.startPoint.X = rectlist[i].X; 
    b.startPoint.Y = (rectlist[i].Y + rectlist[i].Bottom) / 2; 
    b.endPoint.X = rectlist[i].Right; 
    b.endPoint.Y = (rectlist[i].Top + rectlist[i].Bottom) / 2; 
    alllines.Add(b); 
}
```

Your problem is you are just changing the same line and adding it to the list

I.e your list ends up with the same line over and over again

Comment: i check the startpoint of each line and they were not the same

but outside the button click , i check them again and they were same !!

what this mean ?

Comment: It means when you are adding them, you are not doing the right calculations, or if you you are adding them in a loop you are using the same index

Comment: in other words, inside the local region the lines start point is accepted and not the same
but in the paint event and other regions there are the same !!

Comment: My suspicion is the lines are always the same, check when you add them to the list

Comment: for (int i = 0; i < rectlist.Count; i++)
            {
                b.startPoint.X = rectlist[i].X;
                b.startPoint.Y = (rectlist[i].Y + rectlist[i].Bottom) / 2;
                b.endPoint.X = rectlist[i].Right;
                b.endPoint.Y = (rectlist[i].Top + rectlist[i].Bottom) / 2;
                alllines.Add(b);
}

this is the loop !

Comment: Thanks bro i understand i was updated into the same line object ^^